# Django--Is there a way to reference/get the current page URL from within a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

What I had in mind was something along the lines of

```
{% if <"the current page url = '/'"> %}
    {% include '...' %}
```

How can I make this work using template tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `request.path` to get url path.

Other answer :

You can create your custom template context processor where you can store current page url.

Link :  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: Is creating a custom template context processor just another way of saying "create a variable for request.path in your view and pass it to the context"?  
Or is it something inherently different?